# In Visio 2013, how do I apply various styles to a timeline element based on a linked data value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I am building a timeline in Visio 2013 using linked data from Excel.  It took me forever to figure out that I needed to add the names "Task Name" and "Start" to automatically populate milestones on the timeline with relevant data.  Now I need to style each milestone based on it's type as defined by my spread sheet.

For example if I am making a timeline of personal events, I might have this row in the spreadsheet:

```
ID  |  Task Name         |  Start       |  Type
-----------------------------------------------
1   | Bob's Birthday     |  6/10/2014   | Birthday
```

Then I might have an anniversary:

```
ID  |  Task Name         |  Start       |  Type
-----------------------------------------------
1   | Karen's Anniversary|  7/12/2014   | Anniversary
```

How do I apply one color/style to a milestone for birthday, and a different color for anniversaries?

Thanks!